# String was not recognized as a valid parse string to Datetime

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I know there are many related questions but this is something else.

> ExceptionMessage":"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.","ExceptionType":"System.FormatException","StackTrace":"   at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)  at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider)

my code

```
string bornstring = request.BornDate;
var borndate = DateTime.ParseExact(bornstring, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This does not work:

```
string bornstring = request.BornDate;
```

but this works:

```
string bornstring = "10.10.1959";
```

but i am 100% sure that request.BornDate is of type String and exactly the same. I put debugging point and checked in 100 times. no spaces or other characters. exactly the same
[image]

Comment: There is a difference between the code you posted and the debugger screen shot. In the posted code you use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` but the image shows `null` instead.

Comment: There are multiple Unicode characters that visually look like a dot. Or there may be other non-printable characters in the string. Have you checked the exact code-points in question?

Comment: Put "request.BornDate.ToCharArray()" in the debugger's watch expression.  You'll now also unprintable characters that make ParseExact() fail.

Comment: `"10.10.1959" == request.BornDate` returns `true` or `false`?

Comment: @RenéVogt yeah screenshot may not be same, but point remains. Cultureinfo is not the problem.

Comment: @SimonKarlsson where did i say bornstring = 10.10.1959 ?

Comment: @Ani correct. I posted answer below

Comment: @HansPassant you are right on track. I posted answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Ani and Hans was close to it.

Yes screenshot may not have invariantculture but the point remains. Its not the problem.
The problem is as @Ani wrote Unicode characters.
Even though my ajax request sent it to as "10.10.1959", something got appended on the way.

Solution

```
 string bornstring = new String(request.BornDate
                      .ToCharArray()
                      .Where(c => c <= 255)
                      .ToArray()
                   );
```